# Selenium IFrame ScreenShot

Tags: java, c#

how to do a screenshot of IFrame element?
I use this code:

```
public static void SaveScreenShot(IWebDriver driver, IWebElement element)
{
    // Take ScreenCap of Entire Screen
    var screenshotDriver = driver as ITakesScreenshot;
    Screenshot screenshot = screenshotDriver.GetScreenshot();
    var bmpScreen = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(screenshot.AsByteArray));
    // Crop ScreenCap to Element
    var cropArea = new Rectangle(element.Location, element.Size);
    Bitmap bmpCrop = bmpScreen.Clone(cropArea, bmpScreen.PixelFormat);
    //Save
    bmpCrop.Save("D://img//screen.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

But it catch the screen behind of the element, so the main page, not the iFrame. Before doing screenshot I switch to frame:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(puzzleFrame);
```

Comment: try `driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent().Frame(puzzleFrame);`. Also consider that the switching may not be happening fast enough before your screenshot is taken.